# Stripe get product_id / price_id from session object

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, backend, payment

I'm currently using Stripe Webhooks to get notified when user pays for a product. This is working fine. From the payment intent I can get the **Seesion** and the **Customer** Object. But I don't find a way to get the **product_id** or **price_id** for what the user paid.

Does someone know a way to get **product_id** or **price_id** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While creating the Payment Intent, you can store additional information about the object in the **metadata** field.

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    metadata: {
        product_id: '123',
        price_id: '20',
    },
});
```

Once the payment is done, you can retrieve this information from the **metadata** field.

You can do the same for the Session Object as well.

Comment: did this work for anyone? am not sure one can store additional information...can someone correct me if am wrong on this?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the question. As you noticed the Session data included in the `checkout.session.completed` event does not include the `line_items` where the Price ID is associated to the Checkout Session.

`line_items` is one of the expandable properties, so to retrieve the Price ID you'd retrieve the Checkout Session and use [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) to include the line items in the response. There is not a way to configure your webhook to have the data sent to you include this data.

There are two approaches to associating a customer's purchase with a Checkout Session. First, you could store the ID of the Checkout Session in your database alongside the cart or list of items purchased by the customer. That way you if a checkout session is successful, you can look up the cart by ID and know which items were purchased.

Alternatively you could listen for the `checkout.session.completed` webhook event, then when you receive a new notification for a successful checkout, [retrieve the Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) with [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) then use the related price data.

Using stripe-node that would look like the following:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
  'cs_test_xxx', {
    expand: ['line_items'],
  },
);
// note there may be more than one line item, but this is how you access the price ID.
console.log(session.line_items.data[0].price.id);
// the product ID is accessible on the Price object.
console.log(session.line_items.data[0].price.product);
```

To take this a step further, if you wanted more than just the ID of the product, you could also expand that by passing `line_items.data.price.product` which would include the line items their related prices and the full product objects for those prices.

Comment: is there any way to see the price id that was used when looking at the payment on the stripe payments dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

cjav_dev answer is great! Here is the PHP code for the same.

```
use Stripe\StripeClient;
$event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
    json_decode($payload, true), $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
);
$eventObject = $event->data->object;

$stripe = new StripeClient('testsk_ssdfd...sdfs');
$csr = $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve($eventObject->id,
  ['expand' => ['line_items']]
);
$priceid = $csr->line_items['data'][0]['price']['id'];
```

Note the above is only retrieving the 1st line item. You may have to do a loop for all items.

Comment: This works correctly!

I've adapted only one line: `$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('testsk_ssdfd...sdfs');`

Thanks!

Comment: You are correct @InfZero - alternatively you can add a "use statement". Just updated the code to reflect that. Glad it helped you.